# How to add custom fields in wordpress plugin page with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a plugin page where I added some custom fields in order to create a form made with dynamic fields.

On my plugin page, I have an option group with the field_name and the type_of_field.

If the user selects 'select' as type of field, i would like to add dynamically another set of text fields to constitute the select options.

[image: plugin page]

```
//definition of the fields

    public function setSettings()
        {
            $args = array(
                array(
                    'option_group' => 'nsp_form_option_group',
                    'option_name' => 'nps_form_option',
                    'callback' => array( $this->form_callbacks, 'formSanitize' )
                )
            );

            $this->settings->setSettings( $args );
        }

        public function setSections()
        {
            $args = array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'nsp_form_section',
                    'title' => 'Form Manager',
                    'callback' => array( $this->form_callbacks, 'formSectionManager' ),
                    'page' => 'nsp_form_manager'
                )
            );

            $this->settings->setSections( $args );
        }


        // define the fields for creating a form field
        // name
        // type
        // required
        public function setFields()
        {
            $args = array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'field_name',
                    'title' => 'Field Name',
                    'callback' => array( $this->form_callbacks, 'textField' ),
                    'page' => 'nsp_form_manager',
                    'section' => 'nsp_form_section',
                    'args' => array(
                        'option_name' => 'nsp_form_option',
                        'label_for' => 'field_name',
                        'placeholder' => 'eg. Profession'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'id' => 'type_of_field',
                    'title' => 'Type of Field',
                    'callback' => array( $this->form_callbacks, 'selectField' ),
                    'page' => 'nsp_form_manager',
                    'section' => 'nsp_form_section',
                    'args' => array(
                        'option_name' => 'nsp_form_option',
                        'label_for' => 'type_of_field',
                        'options' => array(
                            'textfield' => 'Text',
                            'checkbox' => 'Checkbox',
                            'radio' => 'Radio buttons',
                            'select' => 'Select',
                            'textarea' => 'Textarea'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'id' => 'required',
                    'title' => 'Required',
                    'callback' => array( $this->form_callbacks, 'checkboxField' ),
                    'page' => 'nsp_form_manager',
                    'section' => 'nsp_form_section',
                    'args' => array(
                        'option_name' => 'nsp_form_option',
                        'label_for' => 'required',
                        'class' => 'ui-toggle'
                    )
                )
            );

            $this->settings->setFields( $args );
        }

//creation of fields
public function registerCustomFields()
    {
        // register setting
        foreach ( $this->settings as $setting ) {
            register_setting( $setting["option_group"], $setting["option_name"], ( isset( $setting["callback"] ) ? $setting["callback"] : '' ) );
        }

        // add settings section
        foreach ( $this->sections as $section ) {
            add_settings_section( $section["id"], $section["title"], ( isset( $section["callback"] ) ? $section["callback"] : '' ), $section["page"] );
        }

        // add settings field
        foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {
            add_settings_field( $field["id"], $field["title"], ( isset( $field["callback"] ) ? $field["callback"] : '' ), $field["page"], $field["section"], ( isset( $field["args"] ) ? $field["args"] : '' ) );
        }
    }

// template
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>Form Fields Manager</h1>
    <?php settings_errors(); ?>

    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php 
            settings_fields( 'nsp_form_option_group' );
            do_settings_sections( 'nsp_form_manager' );
            submit_button();
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

I was thinking doing an ajax request 'onchange' and create new fields in php, but then how would I update the template to display / hide the fields ?

Or another approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is possible, but it is also possible (and easier) to do what you want in JavaScript only, without php. I actually did something very similar to what you want to do in my wordpress backend:

1. Decide where you want the new fields to be displayed when you select the corresponding select option. In the HTML of that place, insert an (empty) HTML table with a unique ID.
2. Store the HTML code of new fields supposed to be added / to be shwon when you select the corresponding trigger option in your select menu inside a variable, let's say

`let newRow = "<td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td>";`

,if your table for example contains two columns.

3. When the option you choose as trigger is selected in the select menu, simply:

a) get the (previously empty) HTML table via

`let table = document.getElementById('unique-id)`;

b) In that table, you then insert a new last row (with `insertRow(-1)`).

c) Then you get the last row of the table with `let lastRow = table.rows[-1];` of the "new" HTML table, now containing one more row

d) And then, insert the corresponding new field into it, via `lastRow.innerHTML = newRow;`.

**UPDATE: (In case you want to dynamically use settings fields created in php code)**

1. Create a javascript file, for example update_fields.js. In this file, you define a JavaScript function which does what's written above (or whatever else you want to make happen with your settings field, once the corresponding select option gets selected). Don't type any php code into this javascript file. Simply refer to your settings field in whichever way you want (as when you define a variable). For illustrative purpose, let's use `let settingsField = php_variable.field;`(read until the end and you'll understand this).
2. Use `wp_enqueue_script()` to register and enqueue your javascript file created above onto the settings page. In other words, this will import the javascript functionality created in the file mentioned in step 1. onto your settings page. To do this properly, check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/.
3. Define your settings field you wish to use dynamically if the specific select option is chosen (if not already done) in php code. Store it as a php variable, let's say `$settings_field`.
4. Now you use `wp_localize_script()`. Don't get confused by the name, "localize" here has nothing to do with places or paths, it rather refers to the translation of terms (which is the original purpose of the function; to translate terms in scripts; because the built-in translation of terms is not possible in javascript via WordPress). Anyway, you use the function to get the settings field created as php variable in step 3. and pass it to the javascript file created in step 1. After that, you will be able to use the settings field created in php as a simple javascript variable. To do this properly, check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/. Make sure to use the same $handler as used for wp_enqueue_script() in wp_localize_script().
   According to the variable definition of the `let settingsField`in step 1., for this example to work, you would need to use `"php_variable"` as the `$object name`used in the `wp_localize_script()`function, and `"field" => $settings_field` to assign the `php_variable`object's property accessed via `.field`to your settings field, originally stored as `$settings_field`. This is what will allow you to use your settings field, originally created in php code, dynamically via javascript only, without any need of ajax. Clear?

Comment: Are you create  the fields with the wordpress logic (register_setting, add_settings_section and add_settings_field)  ?

Comment: I used simple HTML code on the settings / admin menu page (on the php file of it), and set the ```onchange``` attribute of the corresponding select element to the javascript function which does what's written above in my answer. 
HOWEVER, if you've already prepared settings fields in php to add them in function of your select choice, you can also pass your programmed settings fields from your php code into your javascript file containing the function, via wp_localize_script(). Like this, you'll be able to use your settings fields dynamically as simple javascript variable(s) via your trigger.

Comment: I am not sure to get it.

Comment: Edited my answer to try to help you, let me know if it's clear

Comment: Really thank you for your tilme. Tell me if I am wrong, but i thing when you are in the amin pages, you don't need to use wp_localise_script. My ajax functiopn works wiothout all this. And also I have no problems with creating an ajax function, defining a php action and send / receive a response.The php function calle by ajax creates a new field to my option group with add_seetings_field(). My problem is how to update my form in the  template with this new field.

Comment: I'm confused now; what exactly do you mean by 'update my form in the template with this new field' ? Do you want the update changes to your form, which are triggered by select choices, to be saved permanently in your form template ? Or what exactly do you want to happen, once you select an option in your "Type of Field" select menu??

Comment: And concerning your comment on the wp_localize_script() function, it is true, yes, you don't necessarily need it for ajax, not at all. But when you employ it, you don't even need to make ajax requests (in your case!). You could then do what you want in pure JavaScript only, without the need of programming any AJAX requests. I explained that to you because you asked about other ideas than ajax in your question, but it's perfectly fine to stick to ajax if you wish to do so. I personally only use ajax if I really need to do things on the server - side, which does not seem to be your case..?

Comment: Yes of course I need to do things on the server, I need to create a new set of fields using the settings API, update the template called by the callback function to display those new fields. Seems you saw in my question just the how to hide / display elements with jjs. Am I right ?

Comment: I found an answer below.

Comment: After the last comment you made I clearly see (now only) what you wanted to do, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first I would edit the title of the question by

**How to add dynamic fields in a form in a plugin page using settings API**

I kind of found a solution, not sure it's the best approach but it works

```
    // ajax function

        const select_field = document.getElementById('type_of_field');
        const form_field_id = document.getElementById('form_field_id');

        select_field.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
             if(!event.target.value) {
                alert('Please Select One');
                return;
             }
             const count = select_field.options.length;

             if(event.target.value == 'select') {
                fetch(ajaxurl , {  
                    credentials: 'same-origin',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                    },
                    method: "POST",
                    body: 'action=update_form'
                }).then(res => {
                    return res.text();
                })
                .then(data => {
                    form_field_id.innerHTML = data;
                });
             } 
        })

    and then I replace all the content of the form (not just the field added)

    public function update_form()
        {
            $field = array(
                'id' => 'option',
                'title' => 'Option',
                'callback' => array( $this->form_callbacks, 'textField' ),
                'page' => 'nsp_form_manager',
                'section' => 'nsp_form_section',
                'args' => array(
                    'option_name' => 'nsp_form_option',
                    'label_for' => 'option',
                )
            );

            add_settings_field( $field["id"], $field["title"], ( isset( $field["callback"] ) ? $field["callback"] : '' ), $field["page"], $field["section"], ( isset( $field["args"] ) ? $field["args"] : '' ) );

            $res = settings_fields( 'nsp_form_option_group' ) . do_settings_sections( 'nsp_form_manager' ) . submit_button();

            echo $res;
            wp_die();
        }

    // form.php (where the form is displayed)
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>Form Fields Manager</h1>
    <?php settings_errors(); ?>

    <form method="post" action="options.php" id="form_field_id">
        <?php 
            settings_fields( 'nsp_form_option_group' );
            do_settings_sections( 'nsp_form_manager' );
            submit_button();
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
```